# PHP - Help me fetch values from this serialize values array in my DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

This is my serialize values in my database when I tried fetching using PHP

```
$mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM wp_hlsq_signups WHERE user_email = 'john.r3@domain.com'" );
$metaData= $mylink->meta;
echo "<pre> $metaData</pre>";
```

**This is the Output:**

```
a:6:{
s:10:"first_name";s:4:"John";s:9:"last_name";s:6:"Ratina";s:9:"user_pass";s:34:"$P$B3EtpszNVkYJseassseaa2$swas";s:10:"user_email";s:14:"john.r3@domain.com";s:10:"user_login";s:6:"john-r";s:4:"role";s:10:"subscriber";
}
```

I just want to display **John Ratina** which is `first_name` and `last_name` in php, how it's possible?

Comment: Your data wasn't serialized properly. It's malformed. How did you serialize it in the first place? Eg. `s:8:"John"` *John* doesn't have `8` characters. And so forth for each.

Comment: i ask right about this, may be string is not correctly taken to the question

Comment: Correct, I didn't know what was s:8, the name was of 8 characters and I simply changed that 8 characters name to John just to hide my name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$metaData= $mylink->meta;
$valData= unserialize($metaData);
echo $valData['first_name'];
```

Comment: Does that work? 'Cause based on your serialized data, it should return an notice like: *Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset x*

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.